# RAILS : undefined method `secret_key=' for Devise:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, devise

I defined a model in rails using command **rails generate model testdetails** . After that I went to db/migrate and wrote the fields for this model

```
class CreateTestDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
   create_table :test_details do |t|
     t.column :TestName ,:string
     t.column :TestType ,:integer
   end
 end
end
```

then i did db:migrate , it throws some error . I google it and found out that it may be coming due to devise version ( I am using devise for authentication) , I updated Gemfile and wrote the version of devise (2.1) and did bundle install . After that I again did db : migrate but it is showing this error

rake aborted!
undefined method `secret_key=' for Devise:Module
/home/vibhor/rails_projects/recruit/config/initializers/devise.rb:7:in`block in '
/home/vibhor/rails_projects/recruit/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vibhor/rails_projects/recruit/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment

what should i do so that this model can be created without any error?  i am using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.0.0

Comment: The error looks to be in initializers/devise.rb, and as migrations require your environment it's loading in all initializers and can't get past the devise one. Take a look there.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is due to gem version so update it to latest version 3.x or remove that line from your `config/initializers/devise.rb file.`

Answer (score 3):

In your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file add this line:

```
config.secret_key = 'Your secret Key'
```

And use `rake secret` to generate your secret key.

There's an [issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2554) open in github if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problems lately. Check devise initializers, as it has changed lately. For me it solved the problem.